# How to count the number of entries under one field heading in database?

Tags: vb.net

I have a database in Microsoft access and I would like to count how many entries are under a single heading in the database heading and then assign it to an integer so that I know how many times I need to run a loop further on in the code. I am using VB language.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: This site doesnt write code to order for you.  Show the code you are struggling with and maybe someone can help.

Comment: You need to write a `SELECT` query for this. Possibly two..one to group and the other to return a single row showing number of rows that the grouping returned.

Comment: Without showing what you have tried and/or stating what specific error you are getting it won't be possible to help you

Comment: I'm not asking for the code to be written, just for some help on how to start off, I don't really know where to start as I understand the select statement but cannot think of a way to adapt the one I have (assigning one field to a variable) to what I need for this solution. I apologise I should have made that more clear.

Comment: You start off by doing some basic research.  You appear to know that the SQL Select statement is involved, but not how to use it.  Try doing a web search search on "ms access sql syntax" and read through the information.

Comment: `I'm not asking for the code`  You also didnt ask a question.  A rather Bad Thing since this is a Q&A site and all.

Answer (score 0):

to Count one uses an Aggregate query.  This is an embedded feature of the Access product.  When in query design mode look for the Sigma icon (like a big E) - and be sure to review some online tutorials on this topic.

In general, looping code is not used in database applications.  Instead one uses record set queries.  For example to change a value from X to Y - one uses a Select Query to first define the records that are to be changed.  Then one uses an Update Query to change the value in those records.  This method runs very very fast where a loop code approach will be very very slow if the record count begins to get large.